# Scrolling Data From Datatable Not Showing on Print Document

Tags: javascript, jquery, printing, datatable, datatables

This is my Datatable code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $('#records').DataTable({
      "scrollX": true,
      "bLengthChange":   false
    });
});
```

Table structure that I want to print:

```
<div style="height: auto;margin-top: 20px;"  media="print" id="prints">
  <table id="records" class="table table-striped table-bordered" width="100%" cellspacing="0">
    <thead>
     <tr class="head-colr">
        <th>sas</th>
        <th>ad</th>
        <th>ds</th>
        <th>sd</th>
        <th>we</th>
        <th>vd</th>
        <th>dsd</th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>davsfvd</td>
        <td>dsdasdsa</td>
        <td>sdsadsdsa</td>
        <td>sdsdsa</td>
        <td>sdsasa</td>
        <td>sdsdsa</td>
        <td>dsads</td>
      </tr>
      @endforeach
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Function for print data: how can I manage the font size here for the print result

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function printDiv(divName) {
     var printContents = document.getElementById(divName).innerHTML;
     var originalContents = document.body.innerHTML;

     document.body.innerHTML = printContents;

     window.print();

     document.body.innerHTML = originalContents;
}
</script>
```

Using this I can print the Datatable data but scroll data is missing how can I manage it or how can I control the font of the print data..

I want the whole datatable data but in my case its not showing the scroll data on print document how can I make the javascript code or font for this.

Comment: Is there any solution for this ???

Answer (score 0):

You really shouldn't put media/styles attributes inside tags, other than being discouraged, it's best for yourself and future maintainability of code to separate concerns and use an external style sheet. Unless you'd like to get mad at your own code when it'll become more complicated, of course ;-)

So, it's better if you have a "generic" plain table in your HTML and then style it according to wether you want it on screen or print.
The best way to manage fonts and everything else for printing etc. is using media queries where you define different css rules for different devices.

Here's a quick introduction from Mozilla Dev Net:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Media_Queries/Using_media_queries

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@media

And the specification from W3C themselves: 
https://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/